# C++11, type deduction of derived class in static method

Tags: c++, c++11, static-methods, template-argument-deduction

Minimal example:

```
class Task
{
public:
  template<typename T, typename... Args>
  static T* make(Args... args) {
    return new T(args...);
  }
}

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class MyTask : public Task
{
public:
  MyTask(A a, B b, C c)
  {
  }
}
```

The `make` factory method exists to get me out of having to supply all the template types when the templated, derived classes are instantiated.

I would like to be able to create an instance of MyTask as succinctly as possible, ie:

```
auto my_task = MyTask::make(a, b, c);
```

However, the compiler is insisting that it can't deduce T, and wants instead:

```
auto my_task = MyTask::make<MyTask<A, B, C>>(a, b, c);
```

It's not a huge deal-breaker, but the repetition seems unnecessary. Is there some way to get it the way I want?

Comment: Why do you think the compiler should be able to deduce `T`?

Comment: Is MyTask supposed to derive from Task?

Comment: I think you mean `template<class T> Task`, `template<typename... Args> static T* make(Args... args)`, and `template<typename A, typename B, typename C> class MyTask: public Task<MyTask<A, B, C>> {` blah blah blah, no?

Comment: @marc-glisse Yes, you are correct. This is a minimal extracted example, which I have fixed.

Comment: @Brian I don't expect it to as written, but I've described the interface I'm wanting, and wondering if someone knows how to template a static method on the type of the class used to identify it.

Comment: @mikepurvis: *... on the type of the class used to identify it* cannot be done. That name is not used to identify anything, but to start start lookup. The actual function is always `Task::make`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `MyTask::make` is not really that, but rather `Task::make`. The name that you use in the call is the start point for lookup, but not the function name. So technically there is no repetition.

There are different things that you could do, like for example, use the CRTP (as Massa suggests in a comment) to have the derived type inject it's type into the base  --at the cost of having different types for different bases, if you have some actual interface you will need to provide the CRTP as an intermediate helper type between `Task` and `MyTask`, or better as an external CRTP helper

```
template <typename T>
struct Maker {
    template <typename ...Args>
    static T *make(Args ... args) { return new T(args...); }
};

class MyTask : public Maker<MyTask>, public Task { ... };

auto task = MyTask::make(a,b,c);
```

Another alternative is to make the function a free function and pass only the type that you want to build:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
T* make(Args ... args);

auto x = make<MyTask>(a,b,c); // only named once here
```

To support the *nice* syntax in the above code for a template without having to provide the template arguments, you can implement `make` in terms of a *template* rather than a *type*:

```
template <template <typename...> class T,
          typename ... Args>
T<Args...>* make(Args... args) {
    return new T<Args...>(args...);
}
```

Comment: Does this handle when MyTask is templated? I don't think it does, because you'd have to pass the full type, including template parameters through to `Maker`.

Comment: @mikepurvis: The CRTP case, the code would be: `MyTask<A,B,C>::make(a,b,c)`, the helper function would be cleaner, and it can be implemented such that the syntax above works. Let me edit that.

Comment: @mikepurvis: Now, a different question (other than the challenge to provide the most succinct syntax) is whether the original idea makes sense or not. Should the `Task` know about the arguments that shall be passed to the derived type constructor? --Probably not.

Comment: Ding ding ding, winner! Did not occur to me that one could template on a template like that—this was exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @mikepurvis: Don't get over-excited with this, as it has a very strong requirement: the created type must be a template with a constructor taking one argument per template argument and of the same type. That is a very strict requirement, and not generally usable...

Comment: It does happen to map nicely to my needs, but thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't make sense for a couple of different reasons - `make()` is a member of `Task`, but you talk about `MyTask::make()`; did you intend for `MyTask` to derive from `Task`? Also, here

```
auto my_task = MyTask::make<MyTask>(a, b, c);
//                  ^^^          ^^^
```

Obviously you cannot use `MyTask` without specifying template arguments.

I think what you were trying to demonstrate was this (I've added perfect forwarding):

```
template<typename T>
class Task
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  static T* make(Args&&... args) {
    return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class MyTask : public Task<MyTask<A, B, C>>
{
    public: MyTask(A, B, C) {}
};
```

And you'd use it as

```
auto my_task = MyTask<int, long, double>::make(10, 20L, 30.);
```

which is quite verbose. This can be avoided by creating a wrapper function that delegates to `Task::make()` (or get rid of the middleman and do the work done in `Task::make` within this wrapper itself, if that's feasible)

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
MyTask<A, B, C> *make_MyTask(A&& a, B&& b, C&& c)
{
    return Task<MyTask<A, B, C>>::make(std::forward<A>(a), 
                                       std::forward<B>(b), 
                                       std::forward<C>(c));
}
```

Intended usage:

```
auto my_task = make_MyTask(10, 20L, 30.);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91907d7287c82ce8)

Another piece of advice is that you change the `make()` function to return `unique_ptr<...>` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: This seems no better than just `auto my_task = new MyTask<int, long, double>(10, 20L, 30.);`. Most of the work is happening in each derived class.

Comment: @mikepurvis I thought the whole point was to avoid mentioning those types explicitly. I'm not sure what you mean by the second sentence. If you mean you need to write a wrapper for each derived class, then yes, you do need to do that. But the wrapper is trivial enough that you can do it using a macro if you wish to.

Comment: @mikepurvis How is this any better (or different) from what I posted 6 minutes beforehand ?

Comment: @mikepurvis Sorry I thought, you had a positive comment here ... my bad

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. +1 To those who understand this (and know the workarounds)

Comment: That seems like an unnecessarily snarky comment. Everything about this is possible in the context of static types; it comes down to a language design decision that types can be deduced in functions but not constructors. (There's [a C++17 proposal](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3602.html) which seeks to change that, fwiw)

Comment: @mikepurvis Don't be so quick to make assumptions. fwiw I was the one to upvote your Q so far; I don't find it illogical as a request, but you're downvaluating answers that are perfectly aligned with the current state of the language. Static polymorphism has its uses and limitations. There is dynamic polymorphism as well; If we're talking in terms of standards to come let me update my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

A helper function would be of value; Then template argument deduction could happen through it

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Task
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    static T* make(Args... args) 
    {
        return new T(args...);
    }
};

// I find it easier to inherit from a class that actually knows what type to  
// return in the "make" function
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class MyTask : public Task<MyTask<A, B, C>>
{
public:
    MyTask(A a, B b, C c) { }
};

// basically this is the function, whose template argument deduction
// eliminates the need to manually specify the angle brackets
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
MyTask<A, B, C>* MakeTask(A const& a, B const& b, C const& c) {
    return MyTask<A, B, C>::make(a, b, c);
}

int main() {
    // now usage only needs the function parameters. This scales to variadic args
    auto my_task = MakeTask(1, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this scenario, the factory is specific to the derived class, so each derived class must have its own `make` method, which kind of loses the point.